# Deployment of angular latest failed on GitHubPages

Tags: angular, git, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my portfolio for testing onto github pages, but am running into an error that I can't find anything on. I have run the following commands:

1. `npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages`
2. `ng build --prod --base-href https://github.com/GrimZero/website.git`
3. `ngh`

This last command is recognized, but executes with the following error:

```
Error: spawn git ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) Emitted 'error' event at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

UPDATE: I have managed to succesfully publish my page to the web by pushing it via my own source control and setting my github to load that page from the docs folder. I am however running into a few errors upon loading that files cannot be found.

Project: https://github.com/GrimZero/Portfolio

Deployed app: https://grimzero.github.io/Portfolio/

UPDATE2: problem resolved, folder path was wrong on the ng build path

Comment: I have tried using my build path with a ' / ' at the front and back with no results.

Comment: Hello, have a look at my post on medium https://medium.com/@miki995/angular-7-deploy-to-github-pages-images-assets-7704f3b2005c

Comment: Going through it, the && operator is telling me that its not a valid statement separator (Referring to step 3)

Comment: Try making it inline. I suppose you pasted it into package.json and it go to new line...

Comment: I threw it into my cli, which was kinda dumb. I had to separate into 2 calls to make it work. As soon as I run the second part of the command I get the same issue. I.E.: npx ngh --dir dist/[Portfolio]

Comment: my version is  "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.5.3"

Comment: for 0.6 check `ng deploy --repo=https://github.com/yourrepo.git`

Comment: Getting closer, now its telling me I need a package for deployment capabitilities. Is there any in particular for deploy to ghp? Which deploy should I be using?

Comment: I haven't tried the new one yet :D

Comment: Something I find weird about your approach btw, you never specify a github account, just a repository. How does the CLI know you have write permissions if you only specify a repository and not an account?

Comment: @MiroslavMaksimovic can I ask you to take a look at my updated post?

Comment: Because repos must be public, is your repo public one? If it is private then you will need more steps I am afraid.

Comment: I have made it public now. and everything works. I have updated my original post to contain updates.

Comment: Nice, I will add answer and you can mark it as correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201558/discussion-between-miroslav-maksimovic-and-torben-van-assche).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Setup:

1.You have an angular project.

2.Install angular-cli-ghpages package from npm like this
'npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages'

3. You can setup npm script like this or run directly in terminal:
"build-and-deploy-gh-pages": "ng build --prod --base-href ./ && npx ngh --dir dist/[reponame]"

Where ./ can be replaced with:
'https://[username].github.io/[reponame]/'

As a matter of fact, in above link you’ll find your github-page.
You’ll be asked for your github username and password to deploy to gihub pages.

This script will create gh-pages branch automatically and setup your repo for publishing online.

 Next step would be to to run this script as:  'npm run build-and-deploy-gh-pages
```

I've wrote an article in Medium about deploying angular on github pages.

Please have a look [here](https://medium.com/@miki995/angular-7-deploy-to-github-pages-images-assets-7704f3b2005c)